# Error reviewing suggested edits on own post

Tags: bug, status-completed

Logged in and got a notification that there was a suggested edit on [my post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67933/unable-to-login-to-new-custom-domain-on-multisite). Reviewed it, approved it, and then got an error:

> You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits.

It appears my approval took effect. Shouldn't have gotten the error.

**Update:** [Here is a video of the bug and process.](http://youtu.be/YEX3IQ0zlAY)

Comment: This should not happen (approving) because of your too low reputation. If so: Please link to the post. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser: Added a [link to the post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67933/unable-to-login-to-new-custom-domain-on-multisite)

Answer (score 5):

With the new just-out-of-beta review system, after reviewing a post, you are immediately presented with a new post to review.

The Suggested Edits review queue requires minimum 2k reputation to review in general, but you're *always* allowed to review your *own* posts, regardless of reputation. In this case, your suggested edit approval was [successfully submitted](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/44/jim-mckeeth?tab=activity&sort=reviews), but you didn't have enough reputation to continue reviewing.

You're right though; the `You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits` message is confusing here. To handle cases like this, we have changed this message to

> Thank you for your review. You need at least 2k reputation to continue reviewing Suggested Edits.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As from your link: that's no bug. That's the "community user"-bot. This little friend is a pretty smart guy who knows in some cases if an edit is valid and takes work from the community.

Comment: Wrong answer. It shows Community because the change was made by someone not logged in. I've added a video showing the process and the error.

Comment: Ehm. Ok. You know that I'm just a user and not someone from the SE/SO stuff, right? I just know that this has been otherwise before. You should post that to general SE/SO meta.

Comment: @kaiser No need to post it to MSO. This is getting seen here as well.

Comment: @AnnaLear Then maybe you want to add an answer yourself to post feedback or updates? Sometimes it feels like standing alone in the woods if no one from the SE/SO stuff answers.

Comment: @AnnaLear Since you have 101 rep on here you could easily reproduce this bug and see if it is valid. Just follow the steps in the video.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth I can't. I'm a moderator, so all my edits just go through regardless of reputation.

Comment: @AnnaLear Make a test account?

Comment: @kaiser Sorry, there's lots of sites and a few of us. :) We *do* see bugs across the network even if we don't respond to all of them right away. I'll be looking at this again on Monday (yes, possibly using a test account) and pointing it out to the devs. Either way, this is getting seen and is getting attention.